# Props not linking with parent instance data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, parent, prop

I have a "Product" component. The data from parent isn't passing to child. It stays set to default value entered from main template. Depending on premium value, shipping is free or costs 2,69.

I tried to understand using VueMastery introduction videos.. But i'm still struggling, can you please explain clear about what's the problem?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        premium: false // Changing the value here doesn't make any change
    }
})
```

```
Vue.component('product', {
    props: {
        premium: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    }, 
    template: ``,
    data() {},
    computed: {
        shipping() {
            if(this.premium) {
                return "Free";
            }
            return 2.69;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<div id="app">
    <product :premium="true"></product> // Changing this, it works..
</div
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `data` from parent as binding source for `product`.

```
<div id="app">
 <product :premium="premium"></product>
</div>
```

Changing `data.premium` in parent should now propagate to the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Boolean

in your case you can try this:

```
<div id="app">
    <product v-bind:premium="premium"></product>
</div>
```

Any change in "premium" should change the component "Product"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here :)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    premium: true, // Changing the value here also works
    shipping: "Free"
  }
})

Vue.component('product', {
  template: '',
  props: {
    premium: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {},
  computed: {
    shipping() {
      if (this.premium) {
        return "Free";
      }
      return 2.69;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <product :premium="premium">{{ premium }} - {{ shipping }}</product>

  <div> {{ premium }} - {{ shipping }}</div>

</div>
<!-- Changing this, it works.. -->
```